# What does Mono Mix in Windows 7 do?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

When you right click on the volume icon, select playback devices, and click properties on "speakers and headphones" and go to levels, there is an option called "mono mix" which only has the mute option. By default it is un-muted.

However, the only difference it seems to make is that when it is muted, the built in laptop speakers (not the headphones) only output treble, no bass. Obviously, this can't be its purpose, and may have something to do with the fact that I have an HP DV7t with beats audio.

In any case, does anyone know what it is *supposed* to do?

Thank you very much,
Blaine

**Edit:** I belive this is my sound card: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_111D="IDT High Definition Audio CODEC"
it is in an hp dv7t-7000 laptop using beats audio

Comment: Every sound driver will have different options for sound properties, my W7 install does not have "mono mix" as my sound card is most likely different as is the driver. You might add your sound card model to your original post.

Comment: " Stereo simply means the mix has two channels (left and right). A mono mix is simply one channel. You combine (or sum) the left and right channels into a single channel"..http://www.homestudiocorner.com/mixing-in-mono/

Comment: Also add your speaker and mic configuration to your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just accidentally found the answer on a completely different search, lol.

Mono mix, oddly, has nothing to do with mono vs. stereo sound. It is the sub woofer built in to the laptop. So muting it turns off the sub-woofer, which would explain why everything becomes treble when it is muted.